# Watch Dogs 1 runs good in windows 7 at low settings but is unplayable in windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, memory, graphics-card, fps

Watch Dogs used to run fine at low settings on a windows 7 pc but on a windows 10 pc it does not give me even 20 fps. Win 7 gave me at least 20-25 fps.
My specs:-

```
       Intel I3 5005u @ 2GHZ
       4 GB DDR3 ram 1600mhz
       Intel HD 5500 Graphics
       Windows 7 (latest updates installed)

       Intel I3 5005u @ 2GHZ
       4 GB DDR3 ram 1600mhz
       Intel HD 5500 Graphics
       Windows 10 (2004 preview build 19041.207)
```

I have dual boot but game runs perfectly in Win 7 and not in Win 10.
I have all the latest drivers for both the OS.
One more thing I noticed is that in Win 10 while playing the game CPU usage was always around 30-50%, ram usage was around 3.1 gb of 3.9 gb and graphics usage was around 20-40% only. I did not check in Win 7.
I even edited the xml file to put graphics setting at lowest but no good happened. Please help!

Comment: Mechanical or Solid State Hard drive? Windows 10 has been proven to run poorly on a mechanical drive compared to solid state (Same could be said for all OSes, but W10 definitely seems to suffer more from this).

Comment: @Sorean Mechanical HDD

Comment: Make and model? 5400 RPM vs 7200 RPM drive?

Comment: @Sorean My hdd is toshiba MQ01ABD100M 5400rpm

Comment: Have manually installed the most recent Intel display drivers that support WIndows 10 released by Intel?  I suspect your performance problems are due to the fact you are using an unsupported version of Windows 10.  You might have to use `Windows 10 version 1909` to get acceptable performance until Intel can release updated drivers that support `Windows 10 version 2004`.

Comment: @Ramhound I have all the latest drivers manually installed for up to Win 10 1909 at least. I think that it's due to Windows preview version only but I have a limited data plan so I cannot download gigs of updates in a day so I would wait until Windows 10 2004 is officially out and I'll let you know then.

Comment: I would not upgrade to 2004 until Intel releases a driver that specifically supports your hardware and 2004.  Which is the reason you should use 1909, since Intel is unlikely to release drivers for your legacy hardware that support 2004

Comment: Hi @Ramhound Yesterday I rolled back windows 10 to 1909 but still no performance improvement! I thought some files had gone corrupt so I performed a clean install of Windows 10 1903 (I still have dual boot) but that also brought no good to me (The game still lags like hell). I noticed that Win 7 uses only 500-900 MB of my ram but Win 10 uses 2.4-3.0 GB of my ram which according to me should be the real problem.Can I do something to prevent this because most of the work I do is from Win 10. I can't every time reboot to win 7 after my work to play games.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please help me further!